# Saving data in SQLYog using Android Studio

Tags: database, android-studio-2.1, sqlyog

I am a beginner in Android Studio and I created a sign up form. I want to save it on SQLYog using a button. Can someone have a tutorial or some source code on how to save it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SQLYog is a GUI Database tool, it's not a database server. how can u connect with SqlYog.
You have to use MySQL server if you are working as localhost.